# Fetching foreign key's tables data from primary key's table and to render to templete in django

Tags: django

These are my models:

```
class Customer2(models.Model):
    Customer_Name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Customer_Address=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Customer_Phone=models.IntegerField()
    Customer_Email=models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    class Meta:
    db_table="Customer_Table"

class Product(models.Model):
    Product_Name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Quantity=models.FloatField(max_length=100)
    Coming_Date=models.DateField(max_length=15)
    Expire_Date=models.DateField(max_length=15)
    Coming_Price=models.FloatField(max_length=50)
    Picture=models.ImageField(upload_to='Images',blank=True, null=True)

class Sale(models.Model):
    Customer=models.ForeignKey(Customer2, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Product=models.ForeignKey(Product, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Quantity=models.FloatField()
    Price=models.FloatField()
    Date=models.DateTimeField()
    Customer_Name1=models.CharField(max_length=20,default=0)
    Product_Name1=models.CharField(max_length=20,default=0)
    class Meta:
    db_table="Sale_Table"
```

I want to get or fetch or show all Sale model( class Sale) data and render to templete  but instead of Customer and Product columns in Sale table(model),I want to show Customer_Name and Product_Name from their own tables what should I do?

Comment: How do you want to "show" the names? Print them out? Display in a Django template?

Answer (score 0):

To access the foreign keys fields, and the fields on those models, you use dot notation:

```
for sale in Sale.objects.all():
    print(sale.Customer.Customer_Name, sale.Product.Product_Name)
```

To render the data in a template, you need to first create a view, and pass data to your template via context:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

from .models import Sale


def sales_view(request):
    sales = Sale.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('your_app_name/sales.html')
    context = {
        'sales': sales,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Then in your template, you can access the foreign keys directly:

```
{% if sales %}
    <ul>
    {% for sale in sales %}
        <li>Customer: {{ sale.Customer.Customer_Name }}</li>
        <li>Product: {{ sale.Product.Product_Name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No sales are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

See the official [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial03/) for more information.

Comment: Million of thanks Sir roob but I want to render all Sale data to templete and show through templete

Comment: Million of thanks from your guidness

Comment: @AfghanSoftwareHouse you can accept / upvote an answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch related fields like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    sales = Sale.objects.all().values('Quantity', 'Customer__Customer_Name', 'Product__Product_Name')
    # you can include all other fields as comma separated values
    return render(request, 'my_template_name.html', {
      'sales': sales,
    })
```

And in templates access like this:

```
 {% for key, value in sales.items %}
      <h3> {{ key }} </h3>
      <ul> 
         <li> {{ value }} </li>
      </ul>
 {% endfor %}
```

I would suggest keeping column names in all lower case as that is the convention like instead of `Customer_Name` just `customer_name` similarly with other fields.